# E: Unable to locate package <packagename> - Heroku

Tags: python, opencv, heroku

I am trying to use Python with opencv on a Heroku application. We are getting import errors. After some quick research, it was suggested to use an Aptfile containing following libraries:

- libsm6
- libxrender1
- libfontconfig1
- libice6

My aptfile is located in the root, named `Aptfile`. There is no extension. It has the following contents:

```
libsm6
libxrender1
libfontconfig1
libice6
```

That's it.

It's in the directory. There is also a `requirements.txt` containing opencv.

When trying to push, we are getting following error:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: ...
remote:        
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> detect app detected
remote: Unpacking Tesseract-OCR binaries
remote: ./
remote: ./bin/
remote: ./bin/tesseract
remote: ./share/
remote: ./share/tessdata/
remote: ./share/tessdata/eng.traineddata
remote: ./lib/
remote: ./lib/libtesseract.so.4
remote: ./lib/liblept.so.5
remote: ./lib/libpng12.so.0
remote: ./lib/libgif.so.7
remote: Building runtime environment for Tesseract-OCR
remote: -----> Apt app detected
remote: -----> Detected Aptfile or Stack changes, flushing cache
remote: -----> Updating apt caches
remote:        Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
remote:        Get:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease [110 kB]
remote:        Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
remote:        Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
remote:        Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages [11.3 MB]
remote:        Get:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg/main amd64 Packages [412 kB]
remote:        Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [1,344 kB]
remote:        Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [2,498 kB]
remote:        Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [1,459 kB]
remote:        Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [2,238 kB]
remote:        Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [2,935 kB]
remote:        Fetched 22.8 MB in 3s (8,303 kB/s)
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote: -----> Fetching .debs for libsm6
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote: E: Unable to locate package libsm6
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Apt app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to <APP>.
remote:
```

As you can see, it cannot find the packages within the Aptfile. What could be the issue? The aptfile does contain the necessary opencv dependencies.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [`libsm6` exists in Ubuntu 20.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libsm6), upon which Heroku's latest stack is based. It is also in Ubuntu 18.04, upon which heroku-18 is based. What stack are you using? And please [edit] your question to show your exact `Aptfile` contents.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I apologize for the delay of my response! I was using Heroku-18 stack. I have edited the question to show the contents of my Aptfile.

Comment: please use `opencv_python_headless` to avoid those dependancies

Comment: @berak I am using the headless version. It was pointed out to me that that was the way to go, so I did it, but it still gave me the errors. I upgraded to the Heroku-20 stack now too.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this @Kwinten?

Comment: I did! I updated all my packages individually, and for some reason that seemed to work :)